# A more efficient way to render animated GIFs in React Native

Tags: react-native, animated-gif

I'm working on a react native app which works with a lot of animated GIFs.

I've tried using the react native documented library *com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0* for animated gif support, yet, the performance of the default Image component is terrible, but using *FastImage* package I am able to get, at maximum, 10 gifs.

As there is the possibility of integrating the native libraries in React Native, I was wondering what could a solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this useful information!

Is it safe to assume that the 10-gif limit you describe means 10 gifs concurrently loaded into the current screen?

Did you notice any performance issues with just 1 gif on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tested a couple ways to increase the performance of loading multiple animated GIFs in React Native:

- The better format for animated pictures is webp (Why?). Once compressed, it can be around 90% more lightweight to be loaded whether in your web app or your mobile app.
- Facebook's Fresco library which is the documented recommended library for rendering gifs and webp files should be upgraded as it provides a better performance for multiple gif loading, and also the original fresco library should be added as a dependency - at the moment, to at least, 1.5.0 or higher, if possible w/ react-native:0.54 -.
- FlatList can be optimized to remove anything that is not on the screen using `removeClippedSubviews` prop. Alternatively, there are third-party libraries such as `recyclerlistview` or lazy loading lists out there.
- Using `fast-image` for caching can also be advantageous in some cases.

Comment: This answer is incomplete because Fresco works only in Android

Comment: fast-image and built in Image componenet both makes app slow on showing animated images.