# Does iOS and Android support animated GIF images with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

im a newbie with react native, and **i would like to know if using the following dependecies:**

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2"
```

**Would i be able to use animated GIF images on iOS and android 
smoothly?**

with smoothly i mean like fast and without any bugs.

¡thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A more efficient way to render animated GIFs in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978958/a-more-efficient-way-to-render-animated-gifs-in-react-native)

Comment: The currently supported formats are png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, webp (Android only), psd (iOS only).

Comment: but can iOS at least support webp?

Comment: __webp (Android only)__ what's not clear here??